# What happens when we start another installed app and we want to run code on return

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I know that from an activity I create I can send an intent to start another installed app.
So if I understand correctly the other app will start and the user now can go back to the starting app either from the recently open apps menu or by pressing back.
My question is: do I understand the flow correctly and is it possible to run code when the user presses back from the other app?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is run code on your `onRestart()` this runs the first time your activity starts, and everytime your activity is resumed (while another activity was  visible on the screen).

Or if the activity you are talking about is a specific activity that you expect the user to return to yours, you can try `startActivityForResult(intent)` then when the said activity "returns" to your activity, you can run some code.

Edit:

You can keep a variable like.

```
boolean isLaunched;
```

Before starting a new app, set it to `true`.

```
isLaunched = true;
startActivity(intent);
```

On your activity `onRestart()` check the variable and act accordingly. Take note that if the user navigates from the started app to another app and then to yours, there is no way for you to know.

Extra: If you plan to do it this way, make sure to save the `isLaunched` variable on your activity `onSaveInstanceState()` in case your app is destroyed due to RAM constrains.

Comment: It is not always certain that the user will return to the first activity in the first app. Also I did not understand how `onRestart` helps for this

Comment: @Jim `onRestart()` will run when your activity resumes after another activity was visible. So if the user visits another activity, and presses back, your activity's `onRestart()` will run. The same goes if the user navigates to your activity from the recent app's menu.

Comment: But how would I know that the code `onRestart` runs after I have started the other app? It would run anyway all the time as part of the normal lifecycle right?

Comment: @Jim You want to run code when user goes from a specific activity to yours? Or you want to run code when you launch another activity and at some point it returns to yours? I'm not sure I understand exactly. What about when you start another app, and the user goes to another app and then returns to yours? do you want it to trigger then ?

Comment: When in my app, the user starts another app and then eventually returns to my (first) app. That's when I want to run code

Comment: @Jim I edited my answer because I wanted to add code too, take a look.